# the work flows and how to design an er model or diagram

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

i am trying to design an `ER diagram or model of a dvd rental system` but i am having problems with the design i have so far i want to put an entity for an administrator so that he can see everything and i also want to modify the customer entity so that the customer can only see what what is in the shop and not everything ,the customer can only check the basics 
here is my `ER MODEL` below

[image: the movie rental system er model]

Comment: What Do you mean by the admin user can see everything? What is everything?

Comment: i want a relationship for example the admin is the one who provides the movies in the store and he is the one who can only rent a movie to a customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All users have to have privileges to access the database.  The Privileges are dependant on the user.The basic privileges are.

```
 SELECT | gives the right to read the table contents.
 INSERT | gives the right to add new rows to the table.
 DELETE | gives the right to remove rows from the table.
 UPDATE | gives the right to update the contents of the table.
```

The customer will have SELECT maybe UPDATE to any table required for his part of the application.

The application administrator can have all the privileges above to all the tables in the application database.

The database administrator will have all the privileges in the database and will GRANT privileges to customer & application administrator

This is a very simplified version and you should research further, especially the database being used

Comment: Reading your latest comment the user should only have SELECT privileges

Comment: i understand but i am trying to get the concept on the ER model for example i will add another entity lets say the admin with attributes stuff name and stuff id but where to put the relationship and how to connect to the other table( like in my diagram above i have for example said the movie entity is related to the producer by the word  directed which means  the movies are directed by producer) i don't know if you understand me??i am getting confused i need a little

Comment: Simplified ER [customer]--<orders>--[admin]--<rents>--[video]